# Search through string and replace parts of the string

Tags: c#, .net

I have a string that contains some random text plus 0 or more span tags.

Like this.

```
Hey <span class="OverLayStyle" style="background-color:#d8dfea">@Peter</span> and <span class="OverLayStyle" style="background-color:#d8dfea">@cara</span> 

Do you like <span class="OverLayStyle" style="background-color:#d8dfea">#Facebook</span>  or <span class="OverLayStyle" style="background-color:#d8dfea">#Google</span> ?
```

I would like to pull out the `span tag` that contains a @ and replace it with an `a tag` like this:

```
<span class="OverLayStyle" style="background-color:#d8dfea">@Peter</span>
```

**TO:**

```
<a href="" class="OverLayStyle" style="background-color:#d8dfea">@Peter</a>
```

Is it possible to do something like this?

Comment: Short answer: yes. What have you tried?

Comment: I tried indexOf(), Contains(), but all the code i wrote got so big to even be good.

Comment: Regex would be useful here.

Comment: Do you want the random text in the final result?

Comment: @FarhanAnam I would like to Replace the span tag

Comment: @FarhanAnam Or it could make things [worse](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/67392): it depends on how random the "some random text" is. Generally an HTML Parser should be used for manipulation of HTML, but if the change is narrowly scoped and specific regular expressions can be a reasonable approach.

Comment: @Richard the regex is just to match the span tags, independent of the 'random text'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
var line = @"
<span class=""OverLayStyle"" style=""background-color:#d8dfea"">@Peter</span>
<span class=""OverLayStyle"" style=""background-color:#d8dfea"">Peter</span>
<span class=""OverLayStyle"" style=""background-color:#d8dfea"">someone@example.com</span>
<span class=""OverLayStyle"" style=""background-color:#d8dfea"">@Peter</span>";

var replaced = Regex.Replace(
    line,
    "<span.*?>@+.*?</span>",
    match => match.Value
             .Replace("span ", "a href=\"\" ")
             .Replace("/span>", "/a>"));


Gives:
  <a href="" class="OverLayStyle" style="background-color:#d8dfea">@Peter</a>
  <span class="OverLayStyle" style="background-color:#d8dfea">Peter</span>
  <span class="OverLayStyle" style="background-color:#d8dfea">someone@example.com</span>
  <a href="" class="OverLayStyle" style="background-color:#d8dfea">@Peter</a>
```

This will only replace the `span` tag when it's content starts with @

Comment: If I understand the problem correctly, the OP wants to replace the `<span` with `<a href=""`. If you set this "href" into the replace expression it will occur in the closing tag too.

Answer (score 2):

You could try this:

```
    string s1="Hey <span class=\"OverLayStyle\" style=\"background-color:#d8dfea\">@Peter</span> and <span class=\"OverLayStyle\" style=\"background-color:#d8dfea\">@cara</span>";
    string s2 = "Do you like <span class=\"OverLayStyle\" style=\"background-color:#d8dfea\">#Facebook</span>  or <span class=\"OverLayStyle\" style=\"background-color:#d8dfea\">#Google</span> ?";

    var sb=new StringBuilder();

    var parts = s1.Split(new string[] { "</span>" },StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    foreach (var s in parts) {
        if (s.Contains('@'))
            sb.Append(s.Replace("<span ", "<a href=\"\" ") + "</a>");
        else
            sb.Append(s + "</span>"); 
    }

    var resultOfs1 = sb.ToString();
    /*
    Hey <a href="" class="OverLayStyle" style="background-color:#d8dfea">@Peter</a> and <a href="" class="OverLayStyle" style="background-color:#d8dfea">@cara</a> 
    */

    sb.Clear();

    parts = s2.Split(new string[] { "</span>" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    foreach (var s in parts) {
        if (s.Contains('@'))
            sb.Append(s.Replace("<span ", "<a href=\"\" ") + "</a>");
        else
            sb.Append(s + "</span>");
    }
    var resultOfs2 = sb.ToString();
    /*
    Do you like <span class="OverLayStyle" style="background-color:#d8dfea">#Facebook</span>  or <span class="OverLayStyle" style="background-color:#d8dfea">#Google</span> ?</span> 
    */
```

Comment: This will fail when using an email adress: like: `<span>someone@whatever.com</span>`

Comment: This is true, but the OP did not state anything like that... It would be easy to get the line with `s.Contains` more specifif if needed. Btw: I like your approach, one up vote from my side...

Comment: I think your solution is straight forward. Normally Regex will make things more difficult. +1 for you..

Comment: You could replace the `Contains('@')` to `Contains(">@")`

Comment: Yes it would be that easy probably... Hey, now the accepted one flipped over to you... Happy coding!

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried string.Replace? :

`string v=yourString.Replace(@"<span",@"yourReplacement");
string v2=yourString.Replace(@"</span",@"yourReplacement");`

To avoid any error you have to assign to a new string

Source: http://www.dotnetperls.com/replace

Comment: Does this as i said, look for those span tags that only contains a @

Comment: It will replace the closing tag but you can put that in your replacement string. The problem is that you have to have a difference between what you want to replace then you would just replace span and get everywhere the same string.